# What makes the Global Compact for Migration so controversial?

Tags: immigration, united-nations

According [to recent news](https://www.france24.com/en/20181219-un-general-assembly-global-migration-pact-usa-israel):

> The UN General Assembly endorsed a sweeping accord to ensure safe and orderly migration on Wednesday, overriding opposition from five countries, including the United States and Hungary. It was approved by a vote of 152-5 with Israel, the Czech Republic and Poland also voting “no” and 12 countries abstaining.

However there don't seem to be any particularly controversial sections [within the official text of the agreement](http://undocs.org/en/A/CONF.231/3), especially compared to previous treaties such as the [1951 Refugee Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_Relating_to_the_Status_of_Refugees). So why exactly did several states vote against adopting this resolution?

Comment: When your country is already overcrowded, why would you want to encourage immigration?

Comment: The title contains the words "for Migration". That is enough for a lot of people to be rabidly opposed to it on general principle.

Comment: Sovereignty. That is the answer. The compact is not an agreement on how countries interact with each other, it is an agreement that regulates how a country acts within its own borders and how it must treat unknown foreigners.

Comment: The short answer is that the controversy isn't about the text, it's about the lies that people are telling about the text.

Answer (score 7):

Migration is controversial so the compact is controversial.

If one of the basis of your political discourse is that immigration is the root of all social evils, painting the compact that as a threat that will force governments to accept immigrants against their will gives for some political points when you reject it<sup>1</sup>.

So, rejecting the compact would appeal to the governments who got elected on this premise, specially if [the people are protesting the government](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/37177/why-does-the-hungarian-government-want-to-allow-delaying-payment-for-overtime-fo). It allows the governments to move the debate towards the immigration issue and paint themselves as defenders of the national independence and sidestep other issues.

Of course, this is not restricted to governments, as political parties everywhere [have mischaracterized the Compact in the same way in order to attack the government](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2018/12/18/belgium-pm-charles-michel-resigns-government-collapses-dispute/).

To use a quote taken [from someone else's link](https://www.stuff.co.nz/national/politics/109486713/new-zealand-votes-for-un-migration-compact-after-legal-advice)

> The Crown Law Office and the Ministry of Foreign Affairs and Trade had provided legal advice that confirmed the UN cooperation framework was neither legally binding nor constraining on the country setting its own migration policies, he[New Zeland Foreign Minister Winston Peters] said.
>   "The legal advice from Crown Law is not surprising but is important advice in debunking falsehoods or misguided perceptions being spread about the implications of this framework."

---

<sup>1</sup>Of course, you could argue that those who signed it are trying to get points for signing a document that says "we are nice people who treat people nicely" but does not compromise them to any practical measure.

Comment: Please remove the Telegraph link, it's both riddled with factual errors as well isn't a support for your link text. There's approximately 0% chance for a snap election and the misrepresentation of the pact was not meant as an attack on the government.

Answer (score 0):

The word controversial might be a bit misused here, because as you said 152-5 is probabaly not a controversial thing. Now assuming you might mean within the countries that voted no, let’s take the US for example. First, Our current president has restrictive views of immigration. In general, he feels his base is motivated by ideas of less migration. Second, he also leans isolationist. I don’t mean that sensationally, he just does not tend to respect international authority as much as others. Even if some of the langauage in this treaty is non controversial, we all know most people will not read it and his base does not want to see the United States attached to this, because of these two key principles they have.

Comment: They aren’t making an argument they are asking a question

Comment: _"152-5 is probabaly not a controversial thing"_ the number of representatives of individual nations voting for or against it isn't any kind of measure of controversy among their respective populations, deliberately obtuse [-].

Answer (score -1):

Short short version: the "Compact" is a threat to decision making by sovereign countries.

From https://www.stuff.co.nz/national/politics/109486713/new-zealand-votes-for-un-migration-compact-after-legal-advice:

> A number of countries, including the United States and Australia, pulled out of the agreement **because of the potential impact on the decision-making of individual countries**.
>
> And National Party leader Simon Bridges said if his party was in government, it would pull out of the compact **because of its potential to restrict New Zealand's ability to set its own migration and foreign policy**.

Comment: The article you linked explicitly says that New Zealand received legal advice saying the compact "did not compromise sovereignty", so how can it be a "threat to decision-making"?

Comment: @sleske - You can find a lawyer to tell you anything you want to hear. Did you read the compact in detail? I did. It basically says "do things our way no matter what your laws say, and you must change your laws to match this". I'm guessing the reason the lawyers said what they did is because it's supposedly "non-binding".

Comment: Well, it isn't binding; it is effectively a statement of intent.

Comment: Even if it isn't binding, countries would be expected to adjust their laws to follow it.  If they won't, why sign?

Comment: This answer needs to be expanded to support how the threat persists through the "non-binding" argument. The conceptual leap is not apparent, which is a major source of the overall controversy.

Comment: @DavidS - it's non-binding legally. It's almost assuredly binding politically - any government that signs it and then violates it will be under threat from opposition demagogues accusing it of being heartless evil child oppressors violating international agreements.

Comment: Who can guarantee that all judges will always ignore this treaty? Note that in the Netherlands several judges have ruled that the non-binding Paris agreement is binding enough so ordered the government to adjust its policy (Urgenda ruling). Who can guarantee me that this won't happen with the next non-binding treaty?

Comment: @Sjoerd - that should be an answer. Please post

Comment: @sleske : _how can it be a "threat to decision-making"_ : presumably they think it's the thin end of the wedge, a possible precursor to later binding agreements, & want to nip those in the bud?

Comment: @Pelinore: To echo user4012 - that sounds like an answer :-). Consider posting it as such.

Comment: @sleske : it's an observation (or merely a suggestion) of possible motives, I wouldn't even call it an opinion, far less an answer (besides it's far to short for an answer, it would need expanding on so posting it as the core of an answer means I'd have to look at the whole issue far more closely than I've time for right now) :)